# TFF: How Can I change the evaluation function of Federated learning

Tags: tensorflow-federated

To implement my code with TFF, I use the method

```
tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation()
```

But I'm not understanding how this method evaluate accuracy across clients. So, like my question indicates, I would like to change the metrics and code of this evaluation funtion in TFF, so how I can proceed, link please of code fucntion.
Thanks!!

Comment: What does the documentation say about this function?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what "change the metrics code of this evaluation function" means, possibly nothing needs to change in `tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation()`.

If you want to add a new metric, this can be implemented on the `tff.learning.Model`.

- If using a `tf.keras.Model` simply add the metric to the list of metrics passed to [`tff.learning.from_keras_model()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/from_keras_model). This will produce an example weighted metric value.
- If not using Keras, you will need to extend the implementation of `tff.learning.Model.report_local_ouputs()` and `tff.learning_model.federated_output_computation` of your subclass. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/259af6a3307ad01af27417cd1b910216e7c2b84c/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/model_examples.py#L96). Notice how the `tff.learning.Model.forward_pass` updates the metric variables, then `tff.learnining.Model.report_local_outputs` computs the final metric value across *local batches*. Finally `tff.learning.Model.federated_output_computation` provides the mechanism for computing global metric values *across clients*.

For reference, the implementation of `tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation()` can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/259af6a3307ad01af27417cd1b910216e7c2b84c/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_evaluation.py#L24) and shows how the `tff.learning.Model` methods discussed above are used together to compute metrics.